# I am trying to click on activity but it show error in the android studio

Tags: android, button, android-activity

```
2020-08-13 17:15:10.339 335-335/? E/netmgr: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:network' service: Invalid argument
2020-08-13 17:15:10.339 335-335/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? In general, people will be more willing to help you with a specific type of problem (and also you avoid getting downvotes) if you post a mcve (minimal complete verifiable example). Please, edit your question to add more information.

Comment: also more detailed error logs would be great